# Select an option in a select element with tag helpers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, tag-helpers

This is my situation: In an ASP.NET Core application, I need to generate the following HTML code in a Razor view from a model instance:

```html
<select name="CultureName">
    <option value="de-DE" data-summary="Deutsch (Deutschland)">* Deutsch (Deutschland)</option>
    <option value="de-AT" data-summary="Deutsch (Österreich)">* Deutsch (Österreich)</option>
    <option value="de-CH" data-summary="Deutsch (Schweiz)">* Deutsch (Schweiz)</option>
    <option value="en-GB" data-summary="Englisch (Großbritannien)" selected>Englisch (Großbritannien)</option>
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^- important!
    <option value="en-US" data-summary="Englisch (USA)">Englisch (USA)</option>
</select>
```

The `CultureName` property of the model has the value "en-GB". The model also has a list of all available options. The separate `data-summary` attribute is supported by the web frontend framework I use and needs to be set on each `<option>` element, along with other attributes left out here for brevity. One of the options is preselected by the `selected` attribute.

I cannot use the predefined `SelectListItem` class because it doesn't support the additional attributes. So I created my own `SelectListOption` class that looks similar but has additional properties. I have a tag helper that allows me to write this:

```html
<select asp-for="CultureName">
    @foreach (var culture in Model.Cultures)
    {
        <option item="@culture"></option>
    }
</select>
```

Here's the code:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("option", ParentTag = "select", Attributes = "item")]
public class OptionTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public SelectListOption Item { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (Item != null)
        {
            output.Content.SetContent(Item.Text);
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("value", Item.Value);
            if (Item.Summary != null)
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-summary", Item.Summary);
            if (Item.HtmlText != null)
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-html", Item.HtmlText);
            if (Item.HtmlSummary != null)
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-summary-html", Item.HtmlSummary);
            if (Item.Selected)
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("selected", true);
            if (Item.Disabled)
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("disabled", true);
            output.Attributes.RemoveAll("item");
        }
    }
}
```

It fills in the other attributes of the `<option>` element from the model. That works nicely, but the selection is ignored when rendering the page. So the user will see a list with all options, but the **current selection is missing**.

I found out that what I do isn't necessarily correct, and I should do this instead:

```html
<select asp-for="CultureName" asp-items="@Model.Cultures">
</select>
```

The predefined select tag helper would then fill in the options for me. But again, I cannot use this because I need additional standard attributes here. So I tried to make this myself, too.

Here's the code but I have no idea what I'm doing there really because there's not much documentation about it:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("select", Attributes = "options")]
public class SelectTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListOption> Options { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (Options != null)
        {
            foreach (var option in Options)
            {
                // TODO: Use HtmlEncoder.HtmlEncode() on values?
                output.Content.AppendHtml($"<option value=\"{option.Value}\"");
                if (option.Summary != null)
                    output.Content.AppendHtml($" data-summary=\"{option.Summary}\"");
                if (option.HtmlText != null)
                    output.Content.AppendHtml($" data-html=\"{option.HtmlText}\"");
                if (option.HtmlSummary != null)
                    output.Content.AppendHtml($" data-summary-html=\"{option.HtmlSummary}\"");
                if (option.Selected)
                    output.Content.AppendHtml(" selected");
                if (option.Disabled)
                    output.Content.AppendHtml(" disabled");
                output.Content.AppendHtml($">{option.Text}</option>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this as:

```html
<select asp-for="CultureName" options="@Model.Cultures">
</select>
```

This seems to work, I get all the options in my select box. But of course now **still without the initial selection**.

Now I'm stuck. How can I get the `selected` attribute to the correct `<option>` element? How can I find out what the current model value of the `<select>` element is? It has an `asp-for` attribute but that's only the name, not the value I need to match.

I'm looking for something like this:

```cs
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (Options != null)
        {
            foreach (var option in Options)
            {
                output.Content.AppendHtml($"<option value=\"{option.Value}\"");
                if (option.Value == CURRENT_SELECT_VALUE_FROM_MODEL)
                    output.Content.AppendHtml(" selected");
                // (Other attributes)
                output.Content.AppendHtml($">{option.Text}</option>");
            }
        }
    }
```

Next I have another requirement: In some places I need to add another page-specific attribute to all `<option>` elements that will be used for other parts of the form:

```html
<select asp-for="CultureName">
    @foreach (var culture in Model.Cultures)
    {
        <option item="@culture" data-separator="@culture.ValueObject.TextInfo.ListSeparator"></option>
    }
</select>
```

This makes available each CultureInfo's `TextInfo.ListSeparator` value to the page scripts through the `data-separator` attribute. This obviously cannot be handled by the default case anymore, so I still need to create the `<option>` elements in a loop myself. Fortunately, this is already covered by my first tag helper so all the extra attributes are already there. But again, the **`selected` attribute is missing**.

While I could try to modify the list of options in the model so that one of them has the `Selected` property set, that is a lot of stupid work that should already be covered by something like `asp-for`.

Here, I also need to find out from each option tag helper whether a specific option should be selected.

Or maybe alternatively, the select tag helper (parent) could find the option element to select, after its content has been processed. So if that's possible I would have to trigger the closing `</select>` tag and iterate all `<option>` child elements to match their `value` attribute and add a `selected` attribute to one of them.

Can tag helpers even help me with that or are they far too limited for that task? How much of a help are these helpers really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the `asp-for`. It's not magic. If you look at the code for one of the built-in tag helpers, you'll see they have property for capturing this, along the lines of:

```
[HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
```

Then, you must use this property to actually set the selected option by reading the value. That said, though, you'd probably be better served by simply inheriting your tag helper from `SelectTagHelper`, and just overriding `Process` to do your own logic. Remember to call `base.Process` as well, though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This has brought me to locate and read the original [`SelectTagHelper`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/SelectTagHelper.cs) and [`OptionTagHelper`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/OptionTagHelper.cs) source code and look up what they do. I now also understand the "magic" of selecting the right option element and was able to do the same.

Comment: Deriving from their classes wasn't an option in the end because their [`DefaultHtmlGenerator`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs) was still limited in how the `<option>` elements were created.